# font size of figure in xaringan slide too small

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts, r-markdown, xaringan

For some rason, `xaringan` is not modifying the size of the font in figures. I created figure `p1` which looks like this (for the sake of the example, I am exaggerating the size of the text).

[image]

However, when I include it in the `xaringan` presentation it looks like this. As you can see the font size if super small. I changed the `fig.retina` option from 3 to 2 to increase a little the size, but it does not change much

```
.left-column[

- first thing

- secong thing

]

.right-column[
'''{r}
p1 
'''
]
```

[image]

I even tried creating a separate css file (figs.css) for the figure and included it using the `theme_xaringan()` funciton of the `xaringanthemer` package.  It is supposed to increase the size of the font, but it still does not work. Notice that I increased the `--base-font-size` to `40px` (I don't know if this is the right way to do it). I see that the title of the axis is modified by the `theme_xaringan()` function but the size of the labels of the axis are not.

this is the figs.css file

```
:root {
  /* Fonts */
  --base-font-size: 40px;
  --text-font-size: 4rem;
  --code-font-size: 0.9rem;
  --code-inline-font-size: 1em;
  --header-h1-font-size: 2.75rem;
  --header-h2-font-size: 2.25rem;
  --header-h3-font-size: 1.75rem;
}
```

This is the Rmarkdown code to include it.

```
.left-column[

- first thing

- secong thing

]

.right-column[
'''{r}
p1 +
  theme_xaringan(css_file = here("figs.css"))
'''
]
```

[image]

I think this should be a very trivial thing to solve but I have not been able to find the problem.

Thank you so much.

Comment: One option would be to increase the font`size` in `geom_text/label_repel` and the `base_size` of the theme.

Comment: Thank you @stefan, but it does not work. As you see in the first image, the font size in `label_repel` is already large enough. It does not matter how large the size is, it does not change in the final graph.

Comment: That seems like a ggplot issue not a xaringan one. Try to set chunk options so the chart is actually smaller, try changing `fig.width` values  or increase the text size directly in your geom